# Comparing the First Names in two population samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics

I'm not great at stats and hope for a bit of help ... 
I have two sets of peoples first and last names the first group has about 5000 unique first and last names and the second about 300.

When I compare the two groups every first name in the smaller group is also present in the larger group and the same for last names.
Ok ... but there are some weird names present in both groups at frequencies that you wouldn't see in the real world. e.g. 60 people called MorkNorg in group 1 and 6 in group 2, but importantly, the data is presented to me as real world data. 
My null hypothesis is that both sets of names were generated from the same pool of names e.g. some sort of random name generation tool.

I'd appreciate some advice on how to prove this? Is it a t test?

Comment: Simply because rare names appear more than you'd expect doesn't mean the sampling is not random.  Unless you know the exact sampling scheme used to build your dataset, you can't say much at all.  For all you know, names could have been randomly selected from the population of all names with differential weights, so that individuals with the name MorkNorg were selected 1 million times more likely than anyone else.  The selection is still random--the probabilities of selection may simply not be equal.

Comment: So lets assume the large dataset is patrons of a restaurant and the small set are servers in that establishment and I tell you that I collected these names by observing people in a real world restaurant. If you looked at the data and saw that there were 60 different patrons called MorkNorg Smith and that 6 of the people serving were also called MorkNorg Smith. Would you think I had really collected the data the way I said I had or would you assume I had used a random name generator to create both sets of data?

Comment: I would entirely believe that.  Especially considering that it's quite common for employees of restaurants to eat at their own establishments and convert from employee to patron.  One might also expect them to dine more often, especially if not prohibited by policy (e.g. having a drink or a small bite after their shift).  (continued)...

Comment: If they  eat there more frequently and you simply sample with replacement patrons, then it's entirely possible you might see some of the employees appear in the larger dataset quite frequently.  I would believe that your sampled with replacement with unequal probability (or in with probability proportional to frequency as a patron/diner, perhaps).  I think you might be confusing randomness with random without replacement and with equal probability of selection.